# Type casting operator is not being called

Tags: c++, c++11, typecast-operator, typecasting-operator

I was trying to do some example code for type conversions between objects, just following what is showed [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

This is the parent class

```
// ParentClass.h
class ParentClass {
public:
    ParentClass();
    virtual ~ParentClass();
};
```

It´s just some concept proof, the only thing it does is print something

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ParentClass.h"
ParentClass::ParentClass()
{
    std::cout << "Parent\tDefault constructor\n";
}
ParentClass::~ParentClass()
{
    std::cout << "Parent\tDestructor\n";
}
```

And then, the derived class

```
// ChildClass.h
#include "ParentClass.h"

class ChildClass: public ParentClass {
public:
    ChildClass();
    // conversion constructor
    ChildClass( const ParentClass& p );
    // conversion from assignment
    ChildClass& operator= ( const ParentClass & p );
    // type-cast operator
    operator ParentClass();
    // destructor
    virtual ~ChildClass();
};
```

And then, the code, is also rather stupid

```
// ChildClass.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "ChildClass.h"

ChildClass::ChildClass()
{
    std::cout << "Child\tDefault constructor\n";
}
ChildClass::~ChildClass()
{
    std::cout << "Child\tDestructor\n";
}
// conversion constructor
ChildClass::ChildClass( const ParentClass& p )
{
    std::cout << "Child\tConversion constructor\n";
}
// assignment operator    
ChildClass& ChildClass::operator= ( const ParentClass & p )
{
    std::cout << "Child\toperator= conversion\n";
    return *this;
}    
// type-cast operator
ChildClass::operator ParentClass()
{
    std::cout << "Child\toperatorParentClass()\n";
    return ParentClass();
}
```

Then, I do some conversions in my main function

```
    std::cout << "calls Parent default constructor\n";
    ParentClass foo;
    std::cout << "calls Parent to child constructor\n";
    ChildClass bar = foo;
    std::cout << "calls assignment operator from child\n";
    bar = foo;
    std::cout << "calls Child type-cast operator\n";
    foo = bar;
    std::cout << "Exit\n";
```

But when I run this the code is not entering the type cast operator from the derived class, it just prints this:

```
calls Parent default constructor
Parent  Default constructor
calls Parent to child constructor
Parent  Default constructor
Child   Conversion constructor
calls assignment operator from child
Child   operator= conversion
calls Child type-cast operator
Exit
Child   Destructor
Parent  Destructor
Parent  Destructor
```

I am at a loss about this, as I tried the code in the link above and it worked just like it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derived-to-base conversion never invokes a conversion function. [class.conv.fct]/p1:

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type
>   (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of
>   that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified)
>   `void`.

In your `foo = bar;`, the `bar` binds directly to the `const ParentClass&` parameter of the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator of `ParentClass`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see, I added that inheritance that wasn´t on the original code. I´ve been scanning both codes for differences and always overlooked that :/